# Mixing Authentication Policies in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I am writing an application that will have some HTML content (display tables etc.) and also have a JSON API.

For normal HTML I use `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` for authentication and `ACLAuthorizationPolicy` for authorization. So the user is presented with a login form and on successful login `auth_tkt` cookie is set. The system works fine.

Now I want to replicate a similar system for JSON API. The problem is that for API requests user will not necessarily be logged in. So each request requires an `api_key` parameter. Based on the key, if I find a valid user, I send back the JSON. Otherwsie I display a 403 page.

One way is to do this in each view

```
api_key = request.GET.get('api_key',None)
user = FrontEndUsers.User_by_api_key(api_key)
if user: 
    #Process view
else:
    return HTTPForbidden
```

However, it seems too much of a boiler-plate to use for each view to do exaclty what an authentication policy would do. Can I specify a separate authentication policy for JSON routes? Or is there any other way of doing this?

**EDIT**

On second thoughts it seems that even with `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy`, I have to do
`security.authenticated_userid()` in every view (If I need authentication info). This I have already factored into a separate function

```
def get_auth_info(): 
    user_id = security.authenticated_userid()
    login_info = {}
    if user_id is not None: 
        login_info['login'] = True
        login_info['logged_in_user'] = FrontendUsers.get_user_by_id(user_id).name
    else: 
        login_info['login'] = False
    return login_info
```

I can include the API_key check function call in this function so that none of my views change (I still only call `get_auth_info()`) and yet I can check if correct API key has been presented.

I'd still like to see if there are any other ways to do this or if there's a problem with my current scheme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention anywhere in here how you're using permissions? Proper usage of permissions and ACLs on your views should prevent you from needing to run that boilerplate at the start of your function. For the simple paste you showed, you simply need a `permission='logged_in'` and an ACE mapping `(Allow, Authenticated, 'logged_in')`, but of course you can get more complex if necessary.

It is not possible to specify different authentication policies for different views in a simple way because authentication policies in pyramid are intended to be global. You can do it globally via the pyramid_multiauth. Or you may write your own policy that wraps multiple policies and dispatches to one or another depending on request properties.

Comment: Yes I have a Root object that defines the ACL and for the views I use `permission=something`(as per the tutorial). The reason I need to run boiler plate is to display the logged in user's name with a logout link or a login link otherwise.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second point just a bit? I know how to write my own policy but How do I ensure the dispatch part?

Comment: I left it ambiguous intentionally because pyramid's auth policies are intended to be global. WSGI apps are all relative, there's no reason that you can't write 2 pyramid apps, one for your api and one for other the public if there are conflicting concerns. If you insist on merging them into one policy then you can inspect the request properties to determine what sub-policy to use and then just call `self.api_policy.unauthenticated_userid(request)` from within your `unauthenticated_userid` method, or whichever other method of the api.

Comment: yes thanks I understand it now. But considering that API doesn't need a full-fledged Policy (For Instance there isn't a need to remeber and forget, plus there can only be an authenticated user ID for an API key), do you think I can run with my current scheme - Use AuthenticationPolicy for HTML requests but use a DB call for API?

Comment: sure you can, you just end up with more boiler plate in your view code as opposed to the declarative configuration, but that can be worked around